# Frame according to interface orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface, uiinterfaceorientation, mobile-devices

I have a UITextField in a UIAlertView. When the orientation changes, I want to update the UITextField's frame because it would otherwise overlap the UIAlertView's buttons. These are the frames:

```
portrait: CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 26.0)
landscape: CGRectMake(12.0, 30.0, 260.0, 26.0)
```

How can I check if the device's orientation has changed **without** using the accelerometer directly?

Should it be in `-[UIViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
   //Landscape Frame
}
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
{
   //Portrait Frame
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how does my app know when it is actually rotated?

Comment: Whenever you rotate your device this delegate will be called - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {